# Problem finding determinant using elementary row or column operations.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm trying to find this determinant using row and column operations, but I got $-9$ as an answer and the right answer is $9$ and I couldn't figure out my mistake.  \begin{vmatrix}
&{1}&&{3}&&{4}&\\
\\
&{3}&&{6}&&{9}&\\
\\
&{1}&&{6}&&{4}&\\
\end{vmatrix} So what I did was I removed $3$ times column $1$ from column $2$, and after that I removed $4$ times column $1$ from column $3$. and I got:  \begin{vmatrix}
&{1}&&{0}&&{0}&\\
\\
&{3}&&{-3}&&{-3}&\\
\\
&{1}&&{3}&&{0}&\\
\end{vmatrix} but now, I tried to calculate the determinant according to first row and got $(-1)^2 *1 *(-9)=-9$ 
 Am I missing something? I would be happy if someone can tell me where my mistake is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The submatrix determinant $\begin{vmatrix}-3&-3\\3&0\end{vmatrix}$ is $9$.

Comment: I would have thought the determinant of your second matrix was lots of zeros plus $1 \times (3 \times 1 - (-3)\times 3)=9$

Comment: Thanks everyone, I messed up with that .. can't believe I have been just trying to find where my mistake is for like 30 mins..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0\\
3&-3&-3\\
1&3&0
\end{vmatrix}=1\begin{vmatrix}
-3&-3\\
3&0
\end{vmatrix}=-3(0)-3(-3)=+9$$